# Trying to learn Rust, getting stack overflow

Tags: rust

I'm only a few tutorials into Rust, but I wanted to try and write something on my own.
I've assembled some code to make a pizzeria, but it's giving me a stack overflow.
This is the most stripped down version that is still having the same issue.
Debugger stops at `fn fmt` in `Display` implementation for `DrinkSize`.

Do you have any pointers as to what have I violated along the way?

```rust
use std::{fmt};
use rand::Rng;
use strum::{IntoEnumIterator, EnumIter};
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

trait Total {
    fn total(&self) -> f32;
}

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum DrinkKind {
    Coke, 
    Water,
    Lemonade,
}

impl fmt::Display for DrinkKind {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string().to_lowercase())
    }
}

impl Total for DrinkKind {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            DrinkKind::Coke => 8.0,
            DrinkKind::Lemonade => 6.0,
            DrinkKind::Water => 4.0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum DrinkSize {
    Small,
    Medium, 
    Big,
}

impl fmt::Display for DrinkSize {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string().to_lowercase())
    }
}

impl Total for DrinkSize {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            DrinkSize::Big => 4.0,
            DrinkSize::Medium => 2.0,
            DrinkSize::Small => 0.0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DrinkOrder<'a> {
    size: &'a DrinkSize,
    kind: &'a DrinkKind,
}

impl Total for DrinkOrder<'_> {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        self.kind.total() + self.size.total()
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for DrinkOrder<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} {}", self.size.to_string(), self.kind.to_string())
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum PizzaSize {
    S30, 
    S40, 
    S50
}

impl fmt::Display for PizzaSize {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", match self {
            PizzaSize::S30 => "30 cm",
            PizzaSize::S40 => "40 cm",
            PizzaSize::S50 => "50 cm",
        })
    }
}

impl Total for PizzaSize {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            PizzaSize::S30 => 18.0,
            PizzaSize::S40 => 22.0,
            PizzaSize::S50 => 28.0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum PizzaDough {
    Thin, 
    Thick,
}

impl fmt::Display for PizzaDough {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} dough", self.to_string().to_lowercase())
    }
}

impl Total for PizzaDough {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        match self {
            PizzaDough::Thin => 0.0,
            PizzaDough::Thick => 2.0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ToppingKind {
    name: String, 
    price: f32,
}

impl fmt::Display for ToppingKind {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.name)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ToppingOrder<'a> {
    kind: &'a ToppingKind,
    number: u8,
}

impl fmt::Display for ToppingOrder<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}x {}", self.number, self.kind)
    }
}

impl Total for ToppingOrder<'_> {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        self.kind.price * (self.number as f32)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct PizzaOrder<'a> {
    size: &'a PizzaSize,
    dough: &'a PizzaDough,
    toppings: Vec<ToppingOrder<'a>>,
}

impl fmt::Display for PizzaOrder<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} on {} with {}", 
        self.size, 
        self.dough, 
        self.toppings
            .iter()
            .map(|topping| topping.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join(", "))
    }
}

impl Total for PizzaOrder<'_> {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        self.toppings.iter()
            .map(|t: &ToppingOrder<'_>| t.total())
            .sum::<f32>() 
        + self.size.total() 
        + self.dough.total()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Order<'a> {
    drinks: Vec<DrinkOrder<'a>>,
    pizzas: Vec<PizzaOrder<'a>>,
}

impl fmt::Display for Order<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Order for:\n - {}\nTotal is {}", self.drinks
            .iter()
            .map(|drink| drink.to_string())
            .into_iter()
            .chain(self.pizzas
                .iter()
                .map(|pizza| pizza.to_string()))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join("\n - "),
            self.total(),
        )
    }
}

impl Order<'_> {
    fn total(&self) -> f32 {
        self.drinks.iter().map(|drink| drink.total()).sum::<f32>()
        + self.pizzas.iter().map(|pizza| pizza.total()).sum::<f32>()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let drink_kinds: Vec<DrinkKind> = DrinkKind::iter().collect::<Vec<DrinkKind>>();
    let drink_sizes: Vec<DrinkSize> = DrinkSize::iter().collect::<Vec<DrinkSize>>();
    let pizza_sizes: Vec<PizzaSize> = PizzaSize::iter().collect::<Vec<PizzaSize>>();
    let dough_kinds: Vec<PizzaDough> = PizzaDough::iter().collect::<Vec<PizzaDough>>();
    let toppings: Vec<ToppingKind> = vec![
        ToppingKind{name:String::from("cheese"), price: 2.0},
        ToppingKind{name:String::from("pinaple"), price: 1.0},
        ToppingKind{name:String::from("paprica"), price: 1.2},
        ToppingKind{name:String::from("corn"), price: 1.0},
        ToppingKind{name:String::from("ham"), price: 1.5}];

        println!("{}", Order {
            drinks: 
                (1..=rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=3))
                    .map(
                        |_| DrinkOrder {
                            size: 
                                drink_sizes
                                    .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
                                    .expect("No drink sizes defined"),
                            kind: 
                                drink_kinds
                                    .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
                                    .expect("No drink sizes defined"),
                        }
                    ).collect::<Vec<DrinkOrder>>(),
            pizzas: 
                (1..=rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=3))
                    .map(|_| {
                        PizzaOrder {
                            size: 
                                pizza_sizes
                                    .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
                                    .expect("No pizza sizes found"),
                            dough: 
                                dough_kinds
                                    .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
                                    .expect("No doughs found"),
                            toppings:
                                (1..=rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=3))
                                    .map(|_| {
                                        let kind = toppings
                                            .choose(&mut rand::thread_rng())
                                            .expect("No topping types were defined");

                                        let number = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..=3);

                                        ToppingOrder { kind, number }
                                    }
                                ).collect::<Vec<ToppingOrder>>(),
                        }
                    })
                    .collect::<Vec<PizzaOrder>>()
        });
    
}
```

Comment: I think to_string calls format

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you! This was the issue.
I'll find some other way to make it lowercase...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack overflow is usually caused by unconditional recursion, creating a very large array, or in rare cases, excessive but not technically unconditional recursion.

Your `Display` implementations have unconditional recursion. Here's just that extracted out.

```rs
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum DrinkSize {
    Small,
    Medium, 
    Big,
}

impl fmt::Display for DrinkSize {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.to_string().to_lowercase())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", DrinkSize::Small);
}
```

You call `self.to_string()`, which is possible because anything that implements `Display` automatically implements `ToString` due to [this impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T).

```rs
impl<T> ToString for T
where
    T: Display + ?Sized,
```

This implementation [calls `fmt` internally](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2524).

```rs
fmt::Display::fmt(self, &mut formatter)
```

So whenever you call `Display::fmt`, it calls `ToString::to_string`, which calls `Display::fmt`, and so on.

To fix this, and since you're using strum, you can [derive `Display`](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/derive.Display.html) for your types instead of implementing it manually, and [use one of the attributes to make them lowercase](https://docs.rs/strum/latest/strum/additional_attributes/index.html#attributes-on-enums).

```rs
use strum::Display;

#[derive(Debug, Display)]
#[strum(serialize_all = "lowercase")]
enum DrinkSize {
    Small,
    Medium,
    Big,
}
```

Remember to fix the unconditional recursion in other types as well.